# iText 7 jumpstart with flat battery

Tags: java, itext7

I  have come back round to the tutorial for 7 after a year but with 7.05 and a brand new version of the script master plugin which us running a Java 8 JVM the issues is still being unable to get past line 4 of the very first example with

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory

The IO jar IS loaded into the JVM as are all dependant files. Is there a known issue here or will this just never work? iText 5 sails along perfectly under exactly the same environment.

Comment: Can you please give some more information?

Comment: using FileMaker as the method of writing Groovy code which can then be 'run' as a function. It loads the jar files I select into the running JVM and then executes the code. just like any other environment I import the classes I need and then perform the function.. happily screenshare to demonstrate.

Comment: Or add just enough code to your question so anyone who spins up a clean VM and installs Java 8 and Groovy can replicate your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing, its not JVM world as you understand it as it is inside FileMaker enabled by a plug-in, no poms no builds, all runtime Groovy

It does appear that a combination of the very latest iText 7 (7.1.0) jars and the very latest version of ScriptMaster allowed me to get code which is woking so I can complete the tutorial